# java.lang.NumberformatException: null

Tags: jsp

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro: `java.lang.NumberformatException: null;`
Meu código:

```java
<%! int a; %>
<%! int b; %>
<%
String getTest = request.getParameter("testJava");

System.out.println(getTest);

%>

<% int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("testJava"));  %>

<%
for(int a = 0; a <= b; a++){

System.out.println(getTest);

}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter("testJava")` está retornando `null`.

Com isso o método `parseInt()` tenta converter `null` para um número inteiro, não consegue e lança a exceção.

Uma forma de deduzir isso é através do nome da exceção que sugere o significado "exceção no formato do número".

Também pode ser verificado na documentação do método [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).